# jQuery remove item from Array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a script that adds all children from the current clicked element to an array. I am trying to remove ALL of the `<br />` tags from this array, but can't seem to figure it out.

Code:

```
childElements = childElements.add( $(currentElem).children() );
childElements = childElements.find('br').remove();
```

I am sure this is simple, I have just been looking over this script for so long that I can't figure it out. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Just to be pedantic, jQuery result collections like `childElements` aren't true JavaScript arrays, but are objects of type `jQuery`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to filter out based on a selector, like this:

```
childElements = childElements.add($(currentElem).children()).not('br');
```

Comment: AWESOME!!!! I can't believe it was something this simple! LOL! I was writing loop after loop trying to figure this out. THANKS!

Comment: Depending on how you're using it, `childElements = childElements.add($(currentElem).children().not('br'));` might be more efficient

Comment: @Eric - definitely depends on how you're using it, if the initial collection is filtered then yes, `.children().not('br')` would be cheaper...it'd be cheaper still to filter them at the end.

Answer (score 2):

[children](http://api.jquery.com/children/) also accepts a selector `children([selector])`.

```
childElements.add($(currentElem).children(':not(br)'));
```